# winit event loop suppressing Vulkan validation output at shutdown

Tags: rust, vulkan

Lately, I have been following [the classic Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers) and have successfully enabled the validation layer features and loaded the `VK_EXT_debug_utils` extension. I confirmed the latter when I forced an error during the instance creation and my registered callback was invoked as expected. Finally I wanted to test the error detection during cleanup and followed the suggestion of the tutorial to comment out destroying the debug utils messenger handle. To my surprise no errors have been reported.

Eventually I was able to track this issue down to `winit` and the `run` method. The way that method hijacks the main thread apparently makes it impossible for the Vulkan debug utils to report any diagnostics at shutdown. For testing purposes I replaced the call to `EventLoop::run` with `EventLoop::run_return` which returns the control flow. With the latter I got the expected error message about the extension leak when the application exits.

I'd like to know how I may reconcile the use of the `EventLoop::run` method with the debug utils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further trial and error and looking through the documentation I finally found a fix for this issue which is still baffling me due to its awful behavior with regards to the implementation details of winit.

The documentation for the `EventLoop::run` method mentions that

> Any values not passed to this function will *not* be dropped.

This means that the struct I wrapped the method call in is not getting dropped and thus the Vulkan instance wasn't destroyed and therefore the debug utils weren't triggered whatsoever.

Since my event loop is currently pretty concise as it does not contain anything yet I had to pass `self` into the closure as follows:

```rust
fn run(mut self) {
    self.event_loop
        .take()
        .unwrap()
        .run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
            *control_flow = ControlFlow::Poll;

            let Self { .. } = self;

            match event {
                Event::WindowEvent {
                    event: WindowEvent::CloseRequested,
                    ..
                } => *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit,
                _ => (),
            }
        });
}
```